# jQuery selector variable syntax error correction

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".className").click(function(){
    var link =  $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    //output is '#myID'

    var findItems = $(link '.mydiv').length; 
    //WRONG
    var findItems = $(link + '.mydiv').length; 
    //WRONG

    console.log(findItems);
    // WRONG NUMBER

});
```

if someone could correct my syntax please? 
suppose to be like `var findItems = $('#myID .mydiv').length`;  but `#myID` should be a variable

Comment: instead of commenting wrong, would you mind putting the exact error on firebug console along with the relevant html code?

Comment: there is no errors, but the length number is not what I am expecting, it is incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var findItems = $(myID).find('.mydiv').length;
```